# Using gRPC/protobuf with a go multirepo and go modules

Tags: protocol-buffers, go-modules, grpc-go

I'm trying to get `protoc` and `protoc-gen-go` to play nice in a multi-repo codebase using go modules.

I've managed to get things more or less working, until I introduced a major version bump in one of my "api" (i.e. protobuf) repos, and I've hit a bit of a barrier.

Here's a simplified picture of my setup:

Let's say I have two repos, `github.com/kpruden/base-api` and `github.com/kpruden/dep-api`.

`base-api` includes `base-api.proto` and `base-api.pb.go` generated from it.

Similarly, `dep-api` contains `dep-api.proto` and the corresponding generated code. In addition, `dep-api.proto` depends on `base-api.proto` via an `import github.com/kpruden/base-api/base-api.proto` statement.

Both `base-api` and `dep-api` use go modules, with `dep-api`'s `go.mod` specifying a dependency on `base-api`.

To make this work, I can run `go mod vendor` in the `dep-api` repo to pull all of its dependencies into a `vendor` directory, then add `-I./vendor` to my call to `protoc`.

This all works well until I decide I need to do a major release of `base-api`. This is done by updating `base-api/go.mod`'s `module` line to end with `/v2`. I have no need to keep version 1 around, so I don't create a `v2` subdirectory in my repo, and the version 2 code and protobuf definitions exist at the root of the repo.

At first, this didn't seem to be a problem. Since I'm not moving any files, `protoc` can still find `base-api.proto`. However, in the generated go code, version 2 of `base-api` must be imported using `import "github.com/kpruden/base-api/v2"`, but `protoc` is generating the code to import it at `github.com/kpruden/base-api`.

My question is: how do I get `protoc` to generate the go code for `dep-api` to import `base-api` at the correct module path? Is this even possible? None of the documentation of either protobuf or gRPC have much of anything to say about go modules. Google has led me to some github issues in these projects that talk about supporting go modules, but they are mostly internal discussions without much in the way of prescriptions, and I've found no mention anywhere of handling major version releases.

Comment: Does using the protoc mapping option as done here work for you:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/0f73133e3aa3bf4505007ebd0cf3508dfc952a22/regenerate.sh#L80

Using this, you can control import paths in the generated code.

Comment: This helps a lot, thanks! By chance do you know where the options to the `--go-out` generator are documented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get something working. The setup I describe in the question is actually pretty close to what ultimately ended up working.

In summary, things mostly work as expected:

1. In the parent module, a major version bump is accomplished by appending `/v2` to the `module` line in `go.mod`. Nothing else is required. In particular, the directory layout in source control doesn't need to have `v2` anywhere.
2. In the child module referencing `v2` of the parent module in go code is handled normally. Using the example above, a simple `import "github.com/kpruden/base-api/v2"` will do it.
3. When including the parent protobuf definitions, use the module path: `import "github.com/kpruden/base-api/v2/base-api.proto"`
4. To be able to generate the bindings using `protoc` use `go mod vendor` to copy dependencies into `./vendor` which will lay them such that the protobuf definitions can be found and the import path in (3). At this point `protoc -I./vendor ...` works as expected, the imports in the generated go source are correct, and everyone's happy :)

Comment: AFAIK including external dependencies in `./vendor` or `./third_party` is the right way to do this.
The hardcore way would be to use something like big boy's tool - Bazel (I am trying to do this right now :) )